# How to avoid to Chrome console to print JSON objects in short forms in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I try to print image as byte array bsae 64 by using `JSON.stringify(...)`

but it prints only short version of it.

Instead:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEoAAABKCAYAAAAc0MJxAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAABHNJREFU\neJztmk1rJEUAhp+q7p6ezEycbIZsTA5uxMSD4B7US0BE8KAXxVMuwurVk/4Kf4D+AEHworiK6E1B\nBAksrCALukjIurLJqvmYmWQyHz1dXR5i2MRsZqp7prsTtp7rdKcf3nRXVVe/YmV1XWMZisxb4KJg\ngzLEBmWIDcqQsQWlAaU10TmZGsbtM3JQGuiqCK1h0nVwBHRUlFtgafm4o5ysNDgC3pifYrlW5lLB\noRVG/Nxo8839Ju1+hCvFaIbnxCdxUJHWOELw/tIMy7XKid+WKj4vTJX44PZfNPsKR6QfVto+iR+9\nINK8Pl89JXXEUxWfawu1zB7BtH0SB1VyHV6dfWzgMS/WyswVPVQGYaXtkyioUGtmfZeq5ww8zhGC\nJ8oeSqebVBY+iYKSCHqRxuRyPaVJe4TKwidZUAK2en02O/2Bxx2EEXfaQeqDeRY+iceoUGuub9QH\nHvP1ZpNGoMhihZC2T+KgClLy4/YBH/+xQ/C/qUQD395v8sW9Om4GS4MsfESS/agjkarnsBOEPFn2\nWZ4uMzfhshsobuwecKvZZcZ32Q8Vodb4UqY2VmXhEyuoINK4QnB1aoKXZio8M1lkrdXj83t17hwE\nAGg0c8UCb85XeX66xNp+j592WtzYbdOLNP4Yn8MsfYyD6qiIpyeLXLsyzdXqxKnfd3oh9b6i4kpm\ni96p/9Zaq8end3e52WhTdEa/u7L2MQqqqzQvz0zy7mKNokz+Hh1p+OTuDl9tNke6s/LwGXqVINI8\nd6nEe0szI0nB4TT+zkKNVy5X6CZcruflM/BKWkPREby9MD3WKf6tKzVqBSf2CjlPn4FBhVqzWPZZ\nKBXGZwVMew7PTk0Qxryp8vQZGFQEzBa9sUodMet76Jh3VJ4+sR7ygzDi+kaDeqBiSbRVxJcbDbZ7\nYazzzpNPrKD+7AR8uLbF7VY3lthGp89Ha1v8uh/vvPPkI2HwS/fxMbMgBQUpYq+BBOBJgXfs9SHp\nYJyXjwsoztgSdgX8tt/lu7/38aTgVrPD4B2fARcS8MN2i16kUVpzs96OvX+dp49YWV3vAv5ZBygN\nYaQ5Ct8RsFjxee3xKpd9l1rBYargnliwBZGm2VfsBortIOT7f/b4pdFB68PbV//3d5K8oOblI1ZW\n1/eAyTiyodb0lGbCkUx6kpIj8aXAFQLF4W9tFdEKIw7CiIIUeCnutWTh4wJBXDFXCFxXoIG9vqLZ\nVxyfWYU4HAeEEJTd9D9GZ+HjAp2kggIe7BZm9/nuTNL0GTrrWQ6RQDVviYuABB7+xdByAomt/hhh\nQzLEBmWIDcoQG5QhNihDbFCG2KAMsa1gQ2wr2BDbCjbEtoINsa1gQ2wr2BDbCjbEtoKNr5HkJNsK\nNse2gg2xrWADbCvYQMi2godgW8G2FWxbweP0sa1gQx/bCjb0sa1gQx/bCjbEtoINGRqUbQUfMnAr\n2LaCHzB0wWlbwYZBPYxHtRUcm0e1FZyYR60VbDFAAq28JS4CEvTveUtcBCTIz/KWuAj8Cy9vAbfs\nZ+QcAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\n
```

I get:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEoAAABKCAYAAAAc0MJxAAAABHNCS…e1FZyYR60VbDFAAq28JS4CEvTveUtcBCTIz/KWuAj8Cy9vAbfs\nZ+QcAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\n
                                                                          ^^^
```

I tried:

```
JSON.stringify(visible_groups);
JSON.stringify(visible_groups, undefined, 2);
```

[image]

How to get rid of it?

**[EDIT]**

I know that its proper print and URL contains full text, but I try to copy to clipboard full version

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

That's just an artefact of how you're looking at it in the Chrome console, it's not in the real string. `JSON.stringify` doesn't arbitrarily elide your data.

Answering your updated question:

> I know that its proper print and URL contains full text, but I try to copy to keyboard full version

`console.log(visible_groups[0].mAvatarImgBase64Str);` (or something like that, obviously I can't see much in that screenshot, no idea which index you want) should dump it to the console in a way you can copy it. If this is coming across the network, you can probably also get it from the Network tab.

Comment: I know by downvote that I mean something else. thanks,

Comment: @fessy: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your comment there...?

Comment: The Idea for testing on mobiles I try to print my model and manually save it as json file to load after on devices. In some cases I got full text but sometimes - short version. If ill print it as separate object you suggested, I need manually run over my big json fie and fix it, what I try to avoid

Comment: If you just want a one-shot copy to clipboard, do `document.write( JSON.stringify(visible_groups) )` and copy it from the browser window.

Comment: @fessy: If you're generating this model on a server and returning it (for instance, via an ajax call), in addition to Juhana's suggestion, you could also just query the thing responding to the ajax directly (with a tool like `wget` or similar), and save the result directly.

Comment: @Juhana thank you, this way works, I would except your answer